# AppInspect failing to install despite following Splunk Dev document instructions

Tags: python, pip

I am currently running Splunk Enterprise 8.0.4 on an AWS EC2 instance, which already has Python 3.7 configured and pip-20.2.2 installed.

Since I am planning to package and bundle our existing search app and other conf files into a private app for deployment to Splunk Cloud, I am trying to install and execute AppInspect beforehand.

I am following the instructions here, under the "Install AppInspect" section with the assumption that a virtualenv is created.  - https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/developapps/testvalidate/appinspect/splunkappinspectclitool/i...

So far, I have the AppInspect tarball downloaded and was able to successfully run the following command, which allows me to upgrade pip:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

However, when I ran the below command to install splunk-appinspect.....

```
pip3 install splunk-appinspect-latest.tar.gz
```

I get the following error:

**/bin/bash: pip3: command not found**

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can proceed from here?

Comment: What does it return when you use "pip3 --version" ?

Comment: bash: pip: command not found

Comment: So, I ended up running the following, which actually generated some logs, but then ended up erroring out:  

sudo -su root python3 -m pip install splunk-appinspect-latest.tar.gz

Comment: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-twxzfo4o/regex/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-twxzfo4o/regex/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-au4gh2j0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7m/regex Check the logs for full command output.